# How $\text{Log}_a(Z)$ = $\frac{\text{Log}(Z)}{\text{Log} (a)}$ ? where $a,z \in \mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can anyone tell me how $\ \text{Log}_a(Z)$  = $\frac{\ \text{Log}(Z)}{\ \text{Log} a}$ where $a,z \in \mathbb C$ ?

I was told that the right hand side is not the definition of the left hand side. It can be deduced from the left hand side.

Can anyone please help me to understand?

Comment: This is simply the change of base rule.

Comment: How ?@ParasKhosla

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/683239/478779

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\log_az=y \implies a^y=z.$ Then take $\log$ on both sides.